# Doctrine Error on Login: Relation Does Not Exist

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine, symfony6

I’m trying to create a simple authentication system with symphony, using postgresql.

First I created a user with make:user, followed by creating the login form through make:auth. I generated the migration with make:migration and executed it.

But trying to login gives this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "user" does not exist
```

So then I noticed that if the user entity was called User, it quoted the table so not to conflict with the keyword. I thought perhaps this quoting was getting in the way so I renamed the table to account_user.

But I still get that error. I’ve tried googling and nothing seems to come up.

I’m using Symphony 6.2. Not sure how to continue from here.

Comment: Could you please share your entity